# How to input number of variables in int form and then label them 1-20 automatically?

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a java program that asks for a number of variables, what the user wants to name them, and then asks for the user to input an equation. The program then writes a program that asks for the variables defined by the user and then solves an equation using the formula the user defined.

I have this so far:

```
int variables;
String equation;


Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the number of required variables for equation (at most 20 variables): ");
variables = reader.nextInt();
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Assign letters or words to each variable: ");
```

I was thinking of making an if statement for each of the twenty possible variables, but that would be incredibly time consuming. I want my program to take the input number of variables, for example four, and automatically name them in the program "variable1", "variable2", etc. I also want to know how to take an input equation using the scanner and use that as a real equation in the program later on.

I was also thinking of somehow using the assigned names defined by the user as the classification of the variable. So if they had two variables and named the first one 'a' and the second 'b', the strings would be referenced as String a and String b, but yet again, I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: It looks like you are using Java, not JavaScript. They are _not_ the same.

Comment: Use an [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), perhaps? Or a [list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)? Or a [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you tag Java, but mention JS?

Comment: Why do you want variables with 1 to 20 instead you can use array, list, map as mentioned in the previous comment. Array or list is meant for such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of size 20,

```
int[] arr = new int[20];
```

and the read the integers.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) arr[i] = reader.nextInt();
```

When you want to use these values in an equation:

```
int value = arr[0]*arr[1]/arr[2];
```

You can't use assigned values defined by the user to set variable names. This defeats the purpose of having variables; you won't know how to reference those variables in code, since the variables don't have a constant name.

Comment: So if I wanted to be able to let the user define these certain variables as different letters or words, I wouldn't be able to do that? Let's say they wanted to input the equation for the quadratic formula, they would need variables a, b, and c. How would the program be written so that the user would be prompted "Enter 'a':, Enter 'b':, and Enter 'c':"?